# How to pass the session value from page 1 ( .js) file to page 2 (.php ) files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want pass the session value from .js files to php files.

```
$.session.set("myVar", TotalHotels);
```

Add this coding in js files and try to retrive in php page like this

```
var myVar= $.session.get('myVar');
```

But i got TypeError: $.session is undefined

Comment: According to your comment below you might want to set a cookie in JavaScript and read it in PHP from `$_COOKIE['name']`

Answer (score 0):

to set a session variable you need to do it in php and use the nomenclature as follows:

```
$_SESSION["username"] = "Bob";
```

and then you need to have `session_start()` a the top of every php page that requires access to the session variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```

and then you access it like:

```
$name=$_SESSION["username"];
```

then you can access that in javascript as follows:

```
var name='<?php echo "$name"; ?>' // gives name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: HI gavgrif,
thanks for your comment. I am set the session in Javascript and retrieve in php.
You send the code opp to that.

Comment: sessions are set and modified on the server side and AFAIK you cannot set session variables with javascript alone on the client side - which is where javascript operates